# MongoDB update 1500 records per request

Tags: c#, mongodb

What is the best approach to update some field in 1500 records by one request with  official C# MongoDB driver ? Records should be updated by the ObjectId. I guess it could be something like the following code:

```
var query = 
Query<Entity>.In(p => p.ID, ids.Select(id => new ObjectId(id)).ToArray());
var update = Update.Set("Field", FieldValue);

EntitydbCollection.Update(query, update);
```

But it doesn't work.
Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `Update` will only update a single item. Alter your code to allow Multi:

```
EntitydbCollection.Update(query, update, 
        new MongoUpdateOptions { Flags = UpdateFlags.Multi });
```

By the way, you're still using the old version of the driver - if you're starting now, I'd suggest using the 2.0 driver (`Install-Package MongoDB.Driver -pre`)

Answer (score 1):

When you want to perform multiple updates at once, you would be well-advised to create a single bulk update with the class [`BulkUpdateRequestBuilder`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.9.2/html/6096bf4a-472e-5caa-3305-ebdd5d22715d.htm).